# How to drag the view without jumping into middle

Tags: swiftui

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f9IMH.png)

This is something like subway map. If I want to drag at other spot if is not center it drags in to center and then I could drag, I don't know how to fix this thing. It feels uncomfortable I feel. Should I try to make custom gesture? (Which I don't know how lol) I would like to take any tips from everyone. Thanks.
To summarize this if i try to drag after zoom in, when it is not in center, even though I want to move right it jumps middle and it doesn’t trigger well. I don’t know how to explain well about this situation but you will found out when you try it with code. Thank you

```swift
import SwiftUI

struct circleView: View {
    
    // drag
    @State var isDragging = false
    @State var position = CGSize.zero
    
    // zoom
    @State var currentAmount: CGFloat = 0
    @State var lastAmount: CGFloat = 0
    @GestureState var dragAmount = CGSize.zero
    
    //color
    @State var color: Color = .green
    
    
    var body: some View {
        
        ZStack(alignment: .leading) {
            // subway map
            Image("subway")
                .resizable()
                .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                .frame(width: 800)
                
            
            //buttons
            
                
            Button {
                color = .black
            } label: {
                Circle()
                    .offset(x: 30)
                    .foregroundColor(color)
                    .frame(width: 30, height: 30)
            }

            
        }
        .offset(x: position.width, y: position.height)
        .gesture(
            DragGesture()
                .onChanged({ value in
                    withAnimation(.spring()) {
                        isDragging = true
                        position = value.translation
                    }
                })
                .onEnded({ value in
                        isDragging = false
                })
    )
        .scaleEffect(1 + currentAmount + lastAmount)
        .simultaneousGesture(
            MagnificationGesture()
            //value : percentage
                .onChanged{ value in
                    currentAmount = value - 1
                }
                .onEnded{ value in
                    withAnimation(.spring()) {
                        lastAmount += currentAmount
                        currentAmount = 0
                    }
                }
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: It is not clear what is wrong and it is not clear what do you want to achieve. Would you elaborate more?

Comment: if i try to drag after zoom in, when it is not in center, even though I want to move right it goes middle and it doesn’t trigger well. I don’t know how to explain well about this situation but you will found out when you try it with code. Thank you